# How to open a popup window when the link is on someone else website

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, popup

I want to make a feature in which I have a video player that I want to show on a new popup window with a specified width and height and the video would be playing in it. Now, It works fine if it's my website, i.e. I had a button that when clicked opens up a new popup window with the video player.
I want to achieve the same result on my user website, i.e. they would just paste a link on their description of my site URL, and if someone clicks on the link it somehow opens up the popup with the video player that I would render inside it

```html
<button id="openButton">Click me</button>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
          
                

openButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
const htmlFileURL = "problem.html";

// Specify the width and height for the new window
const windowWidth = 200;
const windowHeight = 300;

// Calculate the position for the new window (centered on the screen)
const windowX = (window.innerWidth - windowWidth) / 2;
const windowY = (window.innerHeight - windowHeight) / 2;

// Open the new window with the specified dimensions and URL
window.open(
    htmlFileURL,
    "NewWindow",
    `width=${windowWidth}, height=${windowHeight}, left=${windowX}, top=${windowY}`
);         

});
    </script>
```

Comment: Post the code that works for your domain let’s see how we can make it work on another domain

Answer (score 0):

As per your description here is the demo code.

Create a JavaScript embed code that users can copy and paste into their website. This script will bind an event to the link, so when someone clicks on it, it will open a popup.

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EngW7tLk6R8" data-popup-video-link>Watch Video</a>        
    </body>
    <script>
        (function() {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var link = document.querySelector('a[data-popup-video-link]');
            if(link) {
                link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.open(link.href, 'VideoPopup', 'width=640,height=480,toolbar=no,menubar=no');
                });
            }
        });
    })();        
    </script>    
</html>
```

May it work for you! if you need more then please add your full code.

Comment: Is there any way I can do that without asking them to embed the cost into their site? Automatically?

Comment: I get what you mean in the above code, but I was actually looking for a solution that can do that without the user manually had to inject the javascript script into their code

Comment: If you want to enable a feature where users don't need to manually embed code into their sites but still can offer a link that, when clicked, opens the popup video player on their sites, you can leverage a solution using iframes and postMessage for communication.